# Adobe CQ special character issue

Tags: special-characters, aem

Hey i have developed a website using Adobe CQ. When a text containing special character is copied from microsoft word  to CQ text editor and the corresponding content is viewed in preview mode i see special characters coming in some weird format.Please help me out with this issue

Comment: Can you mention which special character you are trying to use? Are you using OOTB text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a text editor or IDE like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), Vim, Sublime, or [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/), etc, that you can use? If not, please do go download one.

To fix this problem right now you can copy and paste your code from Microsoft Word into an IDE, then delete the special characters that are appearing, and finally paste that code into your file or CRXDE. That should help.

In the future you should use a code editor which will likely help with this kind of problem. Good luck! Please let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the richtext editor component in CQ. [You can configure quite extensively](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html).

For the copy&paste problem, you should take a look [at adjusting the editing functions](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.rte.plugins.EditToolsPlugin).